# Elegant way to conditionally combine two strings into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a new column of strings from other columns, where the columns match my criteria.

My goal is to scale this out to read over 12 fields / 30,000 rows of mis-categorized data.

**Example Data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clothes': ['furry boots', 'weird boots', 'furry gloves', 'weird gloves', 'furry coat', 'weird coat'],
      'barn': ['furry animal', 'big animal', 'furry fence', 'old fence', 'furry door', 'old door'],
      'crazy': ['heckin food', 'furry food', 'furry toes', 'old toes', 'furry hat', 'crazy cat']})
df

+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|   |   sparkle    |    misty     |    crazy    |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 0 | furry boots  | furry animal | heckin food |
| 1 | weird boots  | big animal   | furry food  |
| 2 | furry gloves | furry fence  | furry toes  |
| 3 | weird gloves | old fence    | old toes    |
| 4 | furry coat   | furry door   | furry hat   |
| 5 | weird coat   | old door     | crazy cat   |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
|   |   sparkle    |    misty     |    crazy    |                 furry                 |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 0 | furry boots  | furry animal | heckin food | furry boots, furry animal             |
| 1 | weird boots  | big animal   | furry food  | furry food                            |
| 2 | furry gloves | furry fence  | furry toes  | furry gloves, furry fence, furry toes |
| 3 | weird gloves | old fence    | old toes    |                                       |
| 4 | furry coat   | furry door   | furry hat   | furry coat, furry door, furry hat     |
| 5 | weird coat   | old door     | crazy cat   |                                       |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```

**My Current Solution**

```
df['furry'] = ''
df
df.loc[df['sparkle'].str.contains('furry'), 'furry'] = df['sparkle']
df.loc[df['misty'].str.contains('furry'), 'furry'] = df['furry'] + ', ' + df['misty']
df.loc[df['crazy'].str.contains('furry'), 'furry'] = df[['furry', 'crazy']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x), axis=1)
df


+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
|   |   sparkle    |    misty     |    crazy    |                 furry                 |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 0 | furry boots  | furry animal | heckin food | furry boots, furry animal             |
| 1 | weird boots  | big animal   | furry food  | , furry food                          |
| 2 | furry gloves | furry fence  | furry toes  | furry gloves, furry fence, furry toes |
| 3 | weird gloves | old fence    | old toes    |                                       |
| 4 | furry coat   | furry door   | furry hat   | furry coat, furry door, furry hat     |
| 5 | weird coat   | old door     | crazy cat   |                                       |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```

This "works" and I can clean up afterword, but it feels lousy.  Hoping to learn here.

**What I'm trying & struggling with:**

Like I mentioned up top, I want to reduce this to read over 12 columns, many rows and for a library of words. I feel like I'm almost there ...  I've looked at ''.join(), scanned through documentation for concat(), merge() ... I'm just getting stumped.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sparkle': ['furry boots', 'weird boots', 'furry gloves', 'weird gloves', 'furry coat', 'weird coat'],
      'misty': ['furry animal', 'big animal', 'furry fence', 'old fence', 'furry door', 'old door'],
      'crazy': ['heckin food', 'furry food', 'furry toes', 'old toes', 'furry hat', 'crazy cat']})
df['furry'] = ''

words = ['furry', 'old'] # added another word to demonstrate intent with real data
for key, value in df.items():
    df.loc[df[key].str.contains('|'.join(words)), 'furry'] = df['furry'] + ', ' + df[key]

df



+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |   sparkle    |    misty     |    crazy    |                                      furry                                       |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0 | furry boots  | furry animal | heckin food | , furry boots, furry animal, , furry boots, furry animal                         |
| 1 | weird boots  | big animal   | furry food  | , furry food, , furry food                                                       |
| 2 | furry gloves | furry fence  | furry toes  | , furry gloves, furry fence, furry toes, , furry gloves, furry fence, furry toes |
| 3 | weird gloves | old fence    | old toes    | , old fence, old toes, , old fence, old toes                                     |
| 4 | furry coat   | furry door   | furry hat   | , furry coat, furry door, furry hat, , furry coat, furry door, furry hat         |
| 5 | weird coat   | old door     | crazy cat   | , old door, , old door                                                           |
+---+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Does anyone have any pointers / tips?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: @darko check out my answer and let me know if that works out. I have updated the answer

Comment: @darko i have added another solution which looks best way to achieve your task.

Comment: @Poojan Thank you sir!  Left a happy response below your answer.  This is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can use `apply` function

```
words = ['furry', 'old']
for word in words:
    df[word] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(c) for c in x if word in str(c)]), axis=1)
df['all_combined'] = df[words].apply(lambda x:', '.join(x), axis=1)
df = df.drop(words, axis=1)
```

Update: You can iterate over multiple words and create new column for each.
Update2: Again you can combine this using `apply`.

**Solution 2:**

- after getting your full question this looks most elegant solution to me.

```
words = ['furry', 'old']
df['all_combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(c) for c in x if any([w in str(c) for w in words])]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Well that's certainly much cleaner than what I had going before, and works.  Now to just try and incorporate multiple words to check for.

Comment: @drako what do you mean by multiple words? you want to check for more than 1 word like `'furry'` .?

Comment: Right, like `words = ['furry', 'old']`

Comment: for `'old'` do you want to add it to new column  right?

Comment: Yes, ideally, I'd like all these to be summed up into the same column.  I just tried doing `for w in words` and swapping `'furry'` with `w` but it overrides the previous word with the latest, which makes sense

Comment: I wonder if this would be an appropriate attempt for a regex expression?

Comment: @dakro check updated answer dont know if that works for your case?

Comment: Looks like we're getting flagged for discussion?  Your updated solution is a step closer!  If I add the resulting columns together afterword, this will do the job.

Comment: Wow what a great learning point.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help.  This is spot on!  Sorry for the unclear points in my original question.